# Checking relationship existence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scenario in which a user in a `users` table has a profile in a `profiles` table.

I am checking whether a user has filled in particular fields with this query:

```
SELECT users.displayName 
FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN profiles 
ON users.username = profiles.user_username 
WHERE (skills IS NULL OR skills = '') OR (background IS NULL OR background = '');
```

Then I'm using this query to check if the user actually has a profile:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE users.username NOT IN (SELECT user_username FROM profiles)
```

This is because the related field in both tables in the user's username.

Would it be possible to combine the two queries so it reads as select all users who don't have a profile, or, have an incomplete profile?

This is probably incredibly simple but I'm just not connecting the dots.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a left join and che for profile.username is null

```
SELECT users.displayName 
FROM `users` 
LEFT  JOIN profiles ON users.username = profiles.user_username 
WHERE ( (skills IS NULL OR skills = '') OR (background IS NULL OR background = '') )
and profiles.user_username is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from profiles p
                  where p.user_username = u.username and
                        p.skills <> '' and
                        p.background <> ''
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT users.displayName 
FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN profiles 
ON users.username = profiles.user_username 
WHERE (skills IS NULL OR skills = '') OR (background IS NULL OR background = '');

UNION

SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE users.username NOT IN (SELECT user_username FROM profiles)
) x INNER JOIN
```